# React Native zoom sdk ios error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDKSessionContext""

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, webrtc, zoom-sdk

I am adding react-native zoom SDK for audio/video calls from their official plugin [Link](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/react-native)

I have followed their documentation and installed SDK for ios. but when running the build from Xcode gets the following error.

[image]

Also according to their doc when we download the SDK for ios they will get two folders for device only and device and simulator, but these folders are not available in the downloaded zip.

can anybody have implemented the zoom SDK in react-native, can you tell me about its procedure?

Thanks in advance for your help

Edited Question for error code

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDKSessionContext", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdk.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDKVideoOptions", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdk.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDKAudioOptions", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdk.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDKInitParams", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdk.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDK", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkAudioHelper.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkLiveStreamHelper.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkSessionStatisticsInfo.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkUserHelper.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkUser.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkSession.o) objc-class-ref in libreact-native-zoom-video-sdk.a(RNZoomVideoSdkShareHelper.o) ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Please add the error as text too to the question.

Comment: i have edited the question with error code

Comment: did u got the solution